# httpError using mwclient with local MediaWiki

Tags: python, http, mediawiki, wikipedia, mwclient

I try to create a page using mwclient with a local MediaWiki.
With wikipedia.org everything works fine. 
With my local MediaWiki I enter these commands:

```
import mwclient
site = mwclient.Site("192.168.1.143")
```

The result is the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mwclient/http.py", line 152, in request
raise errors.HTTPStatusError, (res.status, res)
mwclient.errors.HTTPStatusError: (404, <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0x104368488>)
```

If I type the IP or the Hostname in my Browser, it works. The same with the ping command.

I used url lib with:

```
a=urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/asdfsf')
a.getcode()
```

and got the `200 OK` Code.

What's the problem here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that mwclient expects the api.php (which is what it uses to access the wiki) to be located at `/w/`, which is the location used for Wikimedia wikis, instead of directly under `/`, which is the default.

Per [the documentation for `Site`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mwclient/index.php?title=Site), you need to use the `path` parameter for that:

```
site = mwclient.Site('192.168.1.143', path='/')
```